# Passing variables to Ajax requesting customer profile details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hi I am trying to create a system where a list of customers is being generated dynamically from a database.

**display_records.php**

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row[‘id’];
    <a href=”#id=”<?php echo $id ?>” onclick="saveData(this.value)" id=”<?php echo $id ?”>view         details</a>
}
```

Within my button I have called a function to then pass on the id variable to an ajax request which carry’s over the variable id to `get_customer_profile.php` page which requested to query the database for the customer profile.

**function.js**

```
function saveData(url)
{
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.click').click(function(){ 
            var target = $(this).attr("id"); 
            var tag = $("<div></div>");
            $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                type: 'post',
                data: ({ mydata: target }),
                success: function(data) { 
                    tag.html(data).dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');
                }
            });
        }); 
    });     
}
```

The issue am having and if anyone can help is the id is not being picked up in my sql query I want the query to use the id and retrieve all the customer profile details by using the id of a single customer profile details to be displayed in a pop up box

**get_cusomer_profile.php**

```
$id = $_GET['mydata'];
$query1 ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id";
```

However if I replace the `$id` to a value this would work. What am I doing wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: You use POST in the ajax call and GET in your ajax to GET a POSTED id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
$id = $_POST['mydata'];
```

instead of

```
$id = $_GET['mydata'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['mydata']; // for post or get
```

Attention how you send ajax request ( **type: 'post'**) if you what to use $_POST or $_GET.

Comment: ok i used $id = $_POST['mydata']; which now displays the id of the individual customer but when i query the database using the $id im not able to pull in the other information attached to the id?